# JSF2.0: Show certain pdf page on load

Tags: pdf, jsf

I'd like to open a PDF in a new Page from JSF2, and display a certain page in this pdf on load.  I have a kind of TOC in my jsf page, and want to jump from there to the page in the PDF directly.

What I know (this is not, what I need, just an example of giving adobe reader and other pdf readers the page I want to jump to):
Something like this will open the page (chose something from the internet):
https://www.cdc.gov/diabetes/pdfs/data/statistics/national-diabetes-statistics-report.pdf#page=10

The #page=10 makes the pdf plugin of the browser display page 10.

Requirements for selecting the PDF:

- PDF is dynamically downloaded from a webservice according to an ID that must only reside in the ManagedBeans, since it's secret, and should not be passed to others (like Session ID...) (below given anser by me passes the ID in the GET-Parameter, which should not be done)
- PDF should not reside in the Filesystem, sinc I don't want the handling of temporary files (below given answer by me actually utilizes PDFs on FS, with stream only it does not work)

Now my real problem: I have to change the URL beeing displayed/used in JSF, but can't use the normal way with  and includeViewParams, because this will insert a "?", and not a "#" in the URL.

Also, I have a backing bean, that gets the content of the PDF from a backend service, based on some other parameters I'm giving, so a solution with  would be cool, but I'm aware that this is probably not possible...

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve this?
I didn't include any code, since it doesn't work anyways, and I probably need a completely new way to solve this anyways...

Comment: server the pdf via a servlet... plain and simple. Nothing jsf related effectively (looking at your required url)

Comment: I clarified the question a bit, Servlet is probably not an option, since I have no access to the secrets I need to open the stream to the PDF

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, Primefaces has this already implemented (although the implementation has it's restrictions):

```
<p:media player="pdf" value="#{viewerBean.media}" width="100%" height="100%">
    <f:param name="#page" value="#{viewerBean.pageNumber}"/>
    <f:param name="toolbar" value="1"/>
    <!--<f:param name="search" value="#{viewerBean.queryText}"/>-->
</p:media>
```

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml

Restriction: Can't read from a stream, at least not very stable.  Save your energy, and write a stream to a temp file, and set this filename dynamically. Not sure, whether this is complete, but you should get the idea:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import java.io.*;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ViewerBean implements Serializable {
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.page}")
  private String pageNumber;

  private File media;

    @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    try {
      media = Files.createTempFile("car", ".pdf").toFile();
      try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(media)) {
        IOUtils.copy(getStreamedContent().getStream(), outputStream);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error(e);
      throw new RuntimeException("Error creating temp file", e);
    }
  }
  public StreamedContent getMedia() {
    try {
      return new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(media), "application/pdf");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      String message = "Error reading file " + media.getAbsolutePath();
      LOGGER.error(message, e);
      throw new RuntimeException(message, e);
    }
  }
}
```

If the pagename is not needed, you could use this:
http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/05/pdf-handling.html

Maybe if you can utilize outputLink for this you'll be lucky, but I ran out of time to test this option.

Comment: Can you please explain where/why all the similar Q/A in Stackoverflow failed for you and that you (think you) need to write it to a file first? In my humble opinion, that is a workaround for a different issue for which you did not find the solution.... Cheers

Comment: None mentioned, how to jump to a specific page in a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Found the (THE) solution; above answher mentions , but this cannot cope with `@ViewScope` beans, and sends many requests to the underlying bean for reading only one InputStream.  I found this not acceptable for load reasons.

So here we go:

1. Create JSF page with `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{documentDownloadBean.writeIntpuStreamToResponseOutputStream}"/>`
2. Put neccessary data for dynamic retrieval of the PDF into flash scope
3. redirect to above JSF page like so: `return "document_search/view_pdf.xhtml?faces-redirect=true#page=" + page;`

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @ViewScoped
   public class DocumentDownloadBean implements Serializable {

     @ManagedProperty(value = "#{documentSearchBean}")
     private DocumentSearchBean documentSearchBean;

     public String activeDocumentToFlashScope(String page) {
       Document document = documentSearchBean.getSelectedDocument();
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("document", document);
       // everything preapared now, redirect to viewing JSF page, with page=xxx parameter in URL, which will be evaluated by adobe pdf reader (and other readers, too)
       return "document_search/view_pdf.xhtml?faces-redirect=true#page=" + page;
     }

     public void download() {
       Document document = (Document) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("document");
       InputStream inputStream = getInputstreamFromBackingWebserviceSomehow(document);
       FacesUtils.writeToResponseStream(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext(), inputStream, document.getFileName());
     }

   }
   ```

Calling JSF Page:

```
        <p:commandLink id="outputText" action="#{documentDownloadBean.activeDocumentToFlashScope(selectedDocument, page)}"
                       target="_blank" ajax="false">
          <h:outputText value="View PDF"/>
        </p:commandLink>
```